# Обращение к API через curl приостанавливает загрузку сайта (выполнение идущего ниже кода). Как это исправить?

Tags: php, api, curl, php-curl

У меня есть php скрипт, в котором происходит обращение к API с помощью CURL. Получив ответ, скрипт выводит его через echo. Обычно там картинка.

Я подключаю этот скрипт в шаблоне сайта с помощью `<?php include_once ...?>`. Скрипт отрабатывает, когда страницы сайта открываются в браузере, и выводит картинку на просматриваемых страницах.

**Проблема:**

Скрипт увеличивает скорость загрузки сайта. Контент после `<?php include_once ...?>` не загружается, пока скрипт не отработает. А его работа зависит от скорости доступа к API, которая изменчива.

**Вопрос:**

Как можно решить эту проблему?

1. Можно ли сделать подключение `<?php include_once ...?>` асинхронно, по аналогии со `<script async ...>`?
2. Или как-то организовать подключение через CURL в фоновом режиме, с подтягиванием результата в шаблон уже после его загрузки (не прерывая его)?

Comment: Отрендерить шаблон, а данные c API подгрузить посредством Ajax.

Comment: Тогда домен API будет виден, а мне нужно этого избежать

Comment: Ну тогда можете попробовать использовать что-то по типу [https://github.com/spatie/async](https://github.com/spatie/async)